# How to evaluate this integral? $\int\sin(wt)\sin(wt+\phi)\,\mathrm{d}t.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Please, how can I integrate the function?

$$\int\sin(wt)\sin(wt+\phi)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sin a\sin b=\dfrac12 (\cos(a-b)-\cos(a+b))$.

Answer (score 1):

From the identity $$\sin\theta\sin\phi = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(\theta-\phi)-\cos(\theta+\phi))$$ we get
\begin{align}
  \int \sin(w t)\sin(wt+\phi)\,dt
      &= \frac{1}{2}\int (\cos(-\phi) - \cos(2wt+\phi))\,dt \\
      &= \frac{1}{2}\left(t\cos\phi - \frac{1}{2w}\sin(2wt+\phi)\right).
\end{align}

Comment: You are faster than [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28xt%29sin%28xt+%2B+y%29+dt), Sir!